# how to trigger if email delivered?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

am using laravel framework for users registration after that the user should activate his account by clicking link sent to his email ,
this scenario works fine with all valid and available mail box .
but some times when the user made mistake typing his email the system will fire the email to none exist email and back with failure message "Delivery to the following recipients failed." in this case he cant login and cant reset or interact with the system , whats is the best practices to avoid this situations ?

Comment: You won't be able to check this directly with PHP. If you're using a mail service (such as Mailgun) that provides an API, you can use it to check deliverability.

Comment: i used Mailgun and had another issues like blocking the ip address from some providers like hotmail .

Comment: Like @aynber recommended, you'll need a third party service.  Mailgun is very good and free up to 10,000 emails.  If your messages weren't being delivered to Hotmail, you should take a look at troubleshooting that - Mailguns docs say that Hotmail requires certain headers as well as unsubscribe links, otherwise they will be blocked.  https://documentation.mailgun.com/faqs.html#does-the-content-of-my-email-matter-for-deliverability

Comment: I've been having similar issues with Mailgun, but my point is to use a mail service with an API that allows you to check the deliverability status of an email.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is allowing the user to login and allowing him to change the email or resend the activation link and blocking his access to other things.

Answer (score -1):

please use laravel queue. Please use third party site like https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

Comment: neither queuing nor either of these platforms are relevant to the question

Comment: the issue not in sending already  emails sent with queue but with delivery